# Como lidar com a comunicação entre containres em um cluster swarm?

Tags: docker

Estou tentando subir um Cluster Elasticsearch no Docker Swarm, porém, não estou tendo sucesso ao lidar com a comunicação interna entre os nós. O cluster sabe e eu consigo acessar o master na porta 9200, porém, ao bater na API do Elastic é possível constatar que o cluster não foi formado por questões ligadas a comunicação entre os nós.

Instrução para subir o serviço:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-stack.yml elastic
```

docker-stack.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  es-master:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2
    hostname: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"
    environment:
      HOSTNAME: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: "password"
    configs:
      - source: elastic_config
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - "node.role==manager"
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - elastic

  es-data:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2
    hostname: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"
    environment:
      HOSTNAME: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: "password"
    configs:
      - source: elastic_config
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - "node.role==worker"
    networks:
      - elastic

configs:
  elastic_config:
    file: ./elasticsearch.yml

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: overlay
```

elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: docker-cluster
network.host: 0.0.0.0

discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3

discovery.seed_hosts:
  - node1
  - node2
  - node3

cluster.initial_master_nodes:
  - node1
  - node2
```

Meu principal ponto de dificuldade está em entender como se dá a comunicação dentro do cluster swarm. Como um container poderia se comunicar com outro?

Answer (score 0):

Qualquer service que esteja nessa rede overlay, enxerga seu elastic master pelo nome "es-master" podendo usar es-master:9200 ou  qualquer worker por "es-data", podendo usar es-data:9200, independente de você ter exposto ou não a porta, como fez no master.

A exposição da porta, diz respeito a quem está fora do cluster, como você, com seu navegador, ou aplicações que estão fora do cluster e precisam se conectar a ele.